# Android gradle plugin multidex ZipException

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I'm trying to use the new multidex option but I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':packageAll[Variant]TestClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/BuildConfig.class
```

I've been able to discover the issue only happens when running the *connectedAndroidTests* task, and not when simply building the project (*build*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue for this, and it's resolved in multi-dex library 1.0.1, see: [Duplicate BuildConfig classes when using multidex test support](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81804)

Try:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
```

Comment: I switched to 1.0.1 and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The last section of [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#testing) specify that

Note: Use of multidex for creating a test APK requires extra setup.

This is probably the reason.

Comment: I am using the `MultiDexTestRunner`. This error happens during the execution of the packaging task which the `connected[Variant]Test` task depends on.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem ? I have the same ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277285/robotium-android-studio