# Robotium + Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robotium

When I run robotium (5.2.1) tests from android studio 1.0 RC 2, I get this following error ==>

```
:app:shrinkDebugTestMultiDexComponents FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkDebugTestMultiDexComponents'.> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

I have no problem to run the application "in normal mode".

Do you know where is my problem ?

Thx in advance

EDIT

According to Jared Burrows's answer I can pass task shrinkDebugTestMultiDexComponents but now I have this problem

```
:app:packageAllDebugTestClassesForMultiDex FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugTestClassesForMultiDex'.> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/BuildConfig.class
```

Comment: I am not sure Robotium supports multidex but you should look into the correct setup here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html. Try to use the test multidex instrumentation support.

Comment: Thx for the link. I think doc is not very clear. Tests worked fine with robotium without multi dex support and now tests are broken.

Comment: Do you need multidex? Did you hit the 65k+ limit? Try using proguard?

Comment: Yes I hit the 65k+ limit. I've already used proguard but I have some trouble. I found this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/i7g7wkpvWVc . I think this is the reason why I have this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android gradle plugin multidex ZipException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033260/android-gradle-plugin-multidex-zipexception)