# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class

Tags: android

Here is my gradle setting.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.usung.smarttrade"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile project(':chatUIDemo')
compile project(':mPChartLib')
compile project(':ptrlib')
compile project(':pullrefresh_library')
compile project(':timessquare_library')
compile project(':update_library')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
compile files('libs/alipaysdk.jar')
compile files('libs/alipaysecsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/alipayutdid.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
compile files('libs/android_api_1.1_forsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')
compile files('libs/easemobchat_2.1.7.jar')
compile files('libs/galaxy_mini.jar')
compile files('libsbipcam.jar')
compile files('libs/photoview_library.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/pushservice-4.5.1.8.jar')
compile files('libs/umeng-analytics-v5.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android gradle plugin multidex ZipException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033260/android-gradle-plugin-multidex-zipexception)

Comment: Thaks for your answer,do you know how to resolve it,I use Android Studio 2.0 preview2  .the gradle version is 2.4

Comment: I resolved the problem that the methed count is out of 65536,just copy multiDexEnabled = true to the gradle build of dependencies  project